# Tackling client side browser caching

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I have an app that uses Vuejs. The app is an appointment system. One of the previous versions of the site had a bug which would causes an input field to be hidden on mobile browsers. The bug was since fixed, and the new version published. The app uses vite for bundling. The domain DNS is by Cloudflare.

Problem: Different clients are seeing different versions of the app, meaning it's being cached.

The current index.html which loads everything has the following:

```
<head>
...
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<script type="9c3c08ece36f7e7da5ac819f-module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-8fc1e8fd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-7b5d238a.css">
</head>
```

Another browser shows this:

```
<head>
...
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<link href="/js/app.88668f01.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="/js/chunk-vendors.44ce8375.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="/css/chunk-vendors.513cdde5.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/app.949f4bc7.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

which was a version pushed several months ago.

Strategies I tried:

1. On Cloudflare, which hosts my DNS records, I disabled cache for this domain, and purged the cache. This didnt have effect.
2. My files already have versioning built in, having different hashes for different versions.
3. My index.html already has meta tags to prevent caching.

What more can I do? How can I make the client browser delete its cache of my site? Next thing that I can think of is to change the subdomain which hosts the site, but though that may fix the issue, the issue may repeat itself. I think the whole index.html is being cached, along with the corresponding number javascript file.

The hosting is being done on a third party side called render, hence server side disabling of caching in not possible. But render.com does state that they dont employ caching.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that your `<meta http-equiv...>` tags don't do anything. `http-equiv` isn't a general-purpose mechanism for supplying header values; rather, it has a few, specific, [enumerated](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-meta-http-equiv) uses, which don't include replacing cache headers.

To solve this problem moving forward you need to use cache headers to communicate your desired caching policy. If you can't control the origin headers, as you imply, you should be able to have Cloudflare [change them](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/edge-browser-cache-ttl/set-browser-ttl/). Consult the Cloudflare documentation.

As for your existing clients, there's no automatic way (without user intervention) to have them delete their cache of your site. It seems likely that your original response didn't have any cache headers at all (you should definitely find out), in which case browsers can decide for themselves how long to cache the page. The good news is that it probably won't be for very long, and this problem should correct itself in a matter of days.

Comment: Thank you. Cloudflare Browser cache TTL was set to 2 minutes. This value was set 2 years ago.